# How can I fix the navigation bar when it is placed on top of the web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just like a page http://9to5mac.com , I want to make the navigation bar fixed when it goes on top of the web page.

Do I have to use Javascript or other way using CSS? and how?

Comment: If the navbar always stays at the same position in the browser window, a simple CSS `position: fixed;` is enough. If you want to toggle between different states based on scroll position, you must use JS, as CSS will not be aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using CSS.
You can use `position:fixed;` to fix the position of the navigation bar.
for example, if your navigation bar has `class="navigation"`
then you can fix its position like this.

```
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  height:50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
}
```

In this code `position:fixed;` fix the position of the div(nav bar) height determines the height of the div `width:100%;` covers full width of the screen while `margin-top: -1.5em;` determines the position of the div from top.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 - currently only in Firefox, via "position: sticky" but it should start working in newest browsers during this year as well (hopefully).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Cross-platform solution: Javascript (jQuery), search for it (keywords: sticky header jquery javascript), there are many nice libs out there.